# has_and_belongs_to_many loads wrong resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have 3 models

```
# generic one
class Someone < ActiveRecord::Base
end

# customer
class Customer < Someone
  has_and_belongs_to_many :groups, join_table: "some_join_table", class_name: "Group"
end

# custom group
class Group < GenericGroup
  has_and_belongs_to_many :customers, join_table: 'some_join_table', class_name: "Customer"
end
```

Let's assume that database is feeded.

When i execute command `Customer.first.groups` I'll get niece array with correct results ([]). When I try to execute same on `Someone` model nothing will happen but when i try do this reverse 'magic happens'

```
Group.first.customers
#=> [<Someone..>]
```

How can i force has_and_belongs_to_many to return right version of Customer class?

Comment: Does `someones` table have a `type:string` column?

Comment: No. It's not STI. Just normal inheritance.

Comment: What is the purpose of this? Are you actually inheriting anything from `Someone` apart from the table? If not, you could just point `Customer` to the same table and inherit from `ActiveRecord::Base`, if you want a different form of the same data.

Comment: `Someone` logic is shared between couple of apps and customer is one specialized case. Probably i can make module which will contain some shared methods and include it in this 2 models but still this will not explain why thing like this happens.

Comment: I think that HasAndBelongsToMany creates some meta model and setups wrong relation class. Because when I remove relation from GenericGroup (about which i didn't mention before :() everything works well.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found this blogpost
http://blog.flatironschool.com/why-you-dont-need-has-and-belongs-to-many/
and decided to change `HABTM` relation to `has_many through`. After change everything works fine.

Comment: Links get old and stop working. Summarise what the link is about, so that future generations may benefit as well.